# ring buffer code not working with pyqgis

Tags: pyqgis

QGIS version 2.18

I am trying to code a function that creates some multi ring buffer. The algorithm is as below:

1. Take a feature
2. Buffer it by a set of distances
3. Do a difference of the buffer geometry minus the feature's geometry to keep the "ring" only
4. Replace the initial feature by the "ring" and start again

the code is below throw works fine during the first buffer but then fall into error

```
def addRing(feature): 
    distances = [5,10,15]
    geom = feature.geometry()
    buffer_features = []
    for distance in distances:
        buffer = geom.buffer(distance,10)
        new_feature = QgsFeature()
        new_feature.setGeometry(buffer)

        new_feature_geom = new_feature.geometry()
        new_feature_clipped = new_feature_geom.difference(geom)

        new_buffer = QgsFeature()
        new_buffer.setGeometry(new_feature_clipped)
        #Add some fields and attribute data to the ring
        buffer_features.append(new_buffer)

        geom = new_feature.geometry()
    return buffer_features
```

The first ring is created but then I get the error:

```
QgsFeature.setGeometry(QgsGeometry): argument 1 has unexpected type 'NoneType'
```

Why? What is the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working code:

```
def addRing(feature): 
    distances = [5,10,15]
    buffer_features = []
    for distance in distances:
        buffer = feature.geometry().buffer(distance,10)
        new_feature = QgsFeature()
        new_feature.setGeometry(buffer)

        new_feature_clipped = 
        new_feature.geometry().difference(feature.geometry() ) 
        feature.setGeometry(buffer)

        new_buffer = QgsFeature()
        new_buffer.setGeometry(new_feature_clipped)
        #Add some fields and attribute data to the ring

    return buffer_features
```

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't return features because you're working with geometries. It's totally redundant to create new features for setting same geometries. It's preferable to return geometries in WKT format. You can handle them easily later. I assume that next code matches your requirement:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

feature = layer.getFeatures().next()

def addRing(feature):

    distances = [5,10,15]

    rings = [ feature.geometry().buffer(distance,-1).difference(feature.geometry()).exportToWkt() 
              for distance in distances ]

    return rings

rings = addRing(feature)

for ring in rings:
    print ring
```

After running it at the Python Console of QGIS with next shapefile:

[image]

I visualized at Map Canvas the first ring printed at Python Console with the help of QuickWKT plugin.

[image]

**Editing Note:**

This is original Blue code's where were fixed all issues:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

feature = layer.getFeatures().next()

def addRing(feature): 
    distances = [5,10,15]

    buffer_features = []

    for distance in distances:
        buffer = feature.geometry().buffer(distance,10)
        new_feature = QgsFeature()
        new_feature.setGeometry(buffer)

        new_feature_geom = new_feature.geometry()
        new_feature_clipped = new_feature_geom.difference(feature.geometry())

        new_buffer = QgsFeature()
        new_buffer.setGeometry(new_feature_clipped)
        #Add some fields and attribute data to the ring
        buffer_features.append(new_buffer)

    return buffer_features

buffer_features = addRing(feature)

print buffer_features[0].geometry().exportToWkt()
```

After running above code at Python Console of QGIS it's obtained this equivalent result:

[image]

Comment: I am using features because for each ring I would like to add some distance information in an attribute field. Your answer is elegant but doesn t work in my case.

Comment: Your code doesn't work and it wont work if you insist to use a wrong approach. Distance information is gotten from geometric object. For this reason you first convert features in geometries. It's totally redundant to create new features for setting same geometries.

Comment: I agree that it redundant to create a new feature and set the same geometry. How would you go about creating rings which have attribute of type texte? For example I have 100 features that I want "ring buffered" and each ring need to have a specific text attribute that way I can merge them down the track. I don't see why I couldn t return a list of features?

Comment: I don't completely understand your question. Are you referring to WKT format?

Comment: Yes, you can return a list of features. I'll see later why your code doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the code section of my initial question to show where I am thinking to add attributes. if that can help. Thanks for your help anyway

Comment: I fixed all issues in your original code. Now, it works as expected. Please, see my **Editing Note**.

Comment: Thanks for you help xunilk but the code doesn't produce the expected outcome. If we consider the set of distances [5,5,8] . The first ring is a 5 meter buffer of the initial feature. The second ring is a 5 meter buffer of the first ring (5 meters away  of the initial feature) and the last ring is an 8m buffer of the second ring. It is similar to the multi ring buffer in ArcGIS https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.4/tools/analysis-toolbox/multiple-ring-buffer.htm .

Comment: It produces that result because it doesn't have the adequate algorithm. It's your fault.

Comment: yeah I figured out that something wasn't quite right. Anyway still trying to solve the ring buffer.